# Using panda gives and error, but same command in cursor works

Tags: python, sql-server, pandas, database-cursor, rfc1738

```
 import pandas as pd
 data_BG2= pd.read_sql("SELECT * FROM [dbo].[Bullgear geometry] WHERE [Bullgear]=?", "3810907-01110", cnxn)
```

where `cnxn` is the connection

This is the first time I am using Panda and I keep getting the following error

> ArgumentError: Could not parse rfc1738 URL from string '3810907-01110'

This error is only there if a searching for a string in the database. if I search for a float or an integer it works.

If I run it via a cursor like below the exact same code works.

```
cursor=cnxn.cursor()
cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM [dbo].[Bullgear geometry] WHERE [Bullgear]=?","3810907-01110")

for i in cursor:
    print (i)
```

Comment: You just asked this exact same question then deleted it. Why?

Comment: Check the documentation.  The substitution parameters are NOT the second paramater to `read_sql`.  You need `pd.read_sql("SELECT...", cnxn, params=("3810907-01110",))`.

Comment: Have you tried reading the [pandas.read_sql()](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_sql.html) documentation yet?

Comment: Thanks Tim, that did the trick. i reread the documentation and i totally ignored the params argument the first time around. Thankyou